# In Flex Application, change total site into a different language?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I am doing a website in flex, In that give option to user to language change option...Suppose if user select Hindi language total site will display in Hindi.. How to do this task?

Answer (score 1):

A solution of this problem is described in Adobe Flex 3 Help:
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=l10n_1.html

And exactly what you want is described here (with an example):
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=l10n_1.html

Comment: yes i tried this links also but i am not getting correct output. i am getting output as square box type that text is unable to understand. What to do?

Comment: I think the problem is caused by a missing or wrong font/charset. Maybe it will be helpful to embed fonts: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=fonts_01.html and http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=fonts_07.html and http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=fonts_10.html#257853